# How to calculate AP Cost for foods & liquids

Tags: self-learning

```
[Item]
Frozen Yogurt

[No. Of Units]
2 L

[AP Cost]
$2.89

[Unit Cost]
0.072 per 50 ML

I need to find the unit cost.
The answer book says 0.072… how did it get that answer?

For reference the formula is:
Unit Cost = As Purchased Cost / Number of Units
```

I've tried the below:
There is 0.05 L in 50 mL

0.05 L x 50 mL = 2.5 ( rounded ) = 3

Total cost =
2.89 / 2L
= 1.445 (1.450)

50 mL = 
50 mL / 2

2.89 / 50 = 0.0578 =

Comment: Get yourself a 2-liter bottle and fill it with water. Find a 50-ml cup. Fill the cup from the bottle and then dump the cup out. Repeat until the bottle is empty. Count how many times you filled the cup. That's the number of units that were purchased by the $2.89.

Comment: Of course you might find it easier to do the exercise on paper rather than find a real 50 ml cup. But don't guess at a formula. Actually simulating the steps of pouring $N$ units from the bottle, or at least a few of the units, might give you a better insight into what kind of formula actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Start with your formula.

Unit Cost = As Purchased Cost / Number of Units

Apply the values that were given.

Unit Cost = $2.89/2 L = 2.89/2 $/L = 1.445 $/L

That answer is accurate, but the answer in the book is per 50 ML, not per 50 ML

You can convert the answer by multiplying it by 1, written in a convenient way, tp get rid of the L units on the bottom and replace it with a 50 ML units on the bottom.  Note that (1 L/ 20*50 ML) = 1.

You also use the units as part of the math now.

Unit Cost = $2.89/2 L * (1 L/20*50 ML) = (289*1)/(2*20) $/ 50 MLL
Unit Cost = 0.07225 $/ 50 ML

Comment: Useful but the random numbers popping up without explanation is confusing.